# Deformation Retract of Complement of Two Linked Circles in $\mathbf R^3$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

On pg. 47 of Hathcer's *Algebraic Topology*, the author discusses the fundamental group of $\mathbf R^n-(A\cup B)$, where $A$ and $B$ are circles in $\mathbf R^3$ which are *linked*.

The author writes that $\mathbf R^3-A\cup B$ deformation retracts to the wedge sum of a torus and a $2$-sphere.

[image]

I was unable to see how this is so. Can somebody please help me visualize a deformation retract.

Comment: Can you see how 1) everything outside the sphere deforms onto the sphere, and 2) everything inside the torus deforms onto the torus?

Comment: Yes. That is clear. The points inside the sphere and outside the torus are difficult to deform.

Comment: Blow up the other circle until it touches the torus. Continue to blow up until everything is pressed to the torus or the sphere.

Comment: @DanielFischer Never discuss this at an airport.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am not sure what you mean. The other(horizontal) circle is not there. We have to deal with points which are not on the other circle. Can you please explain again.

Comment: It's easy to see how you can deformation-retract the complement of the other circle to the complement of a solid torus whose soul is the other circle without moving any point at a distance greater than $\varepsilon$ from the circle. Now imagine that the boundary of the solid torus is made of balloon rubber, and that the space inside the sphere with the two tori removed is filled with a really soft and very compressible substance. Something [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton_candy), only more so. Now inflate the small torus, considering the sphere and the first torus rigid.

Comment: The cotton candy gets compressed as our air-filled rubber torus expands, and the rubber torus is eventually pressed completely against the rigid surfaces of the sphere and the first torus.

Comment: I think I get the idea. Seems a bit difficult to formalize. But yeah, it's quite neat.

Comment: @DanielFischer Suppose instead of another missing circle, we had a missing point (hence the construction would look exactly like above, but with the other circle (i.e., the one not covered by torus) replaced with a single missing point). In this case, the fattening argument should fail, I think, since that space is of a different homotopy class. But where does it fail? Can't the missing point be blown up?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 We can blow up the point hole. But the boundary of the blown-up point is (topologically) a sphere, and when that wraps around the solid torus, two parts of the sphere touch inside the central hole of the torus, making a membrane that does not dissolve.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

To see the deformation retraction, see the flow lines in the diagram below. It shows the flow lines in the vertical and horizontal slices. For the intermediary slices, we gradually move from horizontal slice to the vertical slice.

(In the diagram, dashed circles are the slices of the torus; bold circles and points are the slices of the removed circles).

[image]

Comment: The picture here "https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt7WE.png" is relevant to the discussion. What is the appropriate place to post it? Should I post it in a comment?

Comment: I added your image to your post. IIRC you need something like 25 rep points to add the image yourself. I also handled the flags. It seems to me that the votes to close came because the first version of your answer sounded a bit like "I, too, have this same question" to the voters. That would be a valid reason to vote to delete, because in this slot you should only post answers. A partial answer, marked as such (like you did), is fine. Welcome to the site. We are a bit strict about a few things. You will learn the do's and do-not's quickly enough :-)